# HashMap with Null Key and Null Value

Tags: java, collections, null, hashmap, hashcode

Consider the following Code :

```
import java.util.*;

class Employee {
    
    String name;
    
    public Employee(String nm) {
        this.name=nm;
    }
}

public class HashMapKeyNullValue {
    
    Employee e1;
    
    public void display(){

        Employee e2=null;
        Map map=new HashMap();

        map.put(e2, "25");
        System.out.println("Getting the Value When e2 is set as KEY");
        System.out.println("e2 : "+map.get(e2));
        System.out.println("e1 : "+map.get(e1));
        System.out.println("null : "+map.get(null));

        map.put(e1, "");
        System.out.println("Getting the Value when e1 is set as KEY");
        System.out.println("e2 : "+map.get(e2));
        System.out.println("e1 : "+map.get(e1));
        System.out.println("null : "+map.get(null));

        map.put(null, null);   // null as key and null as value
        System.out.println("Getting the Value when setting null as KEY and null as value");
        System.out.println("e2 : "+map.get(e2));
        System.out.println("e1 : "+map.get(e1));
        System.out.println("null : "+map.get(null));

        map.put(null, "30");
        System.out.println("Getting the Value when setting only null as KEY");
        System.out.println("e2 : "+map.get(e2));
        System.out.println("e1 : "+map.get(e1));
        System.out.println("null : "+map.get(null));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new HashMapKeyNullValue().display();
        
    }
}
```

The Output of program is :

```
Getting the Value When e2 is set as KEY
e2 : 25
e1 : 25
null : 25
Getting the Value when e1 is set as KEY
e2 : 
e1 : 
null : 
Getting the Value when setting null as KEY and null as value
e2 : null
e1 : null
null : null
Getting the Value when setting only null as KEY
e2 : 30
e1 : 30
null : 30
```

Here how `e1, e2, and null` as keys are related to each other. Are all three assigned to same hashcode? If yes, WHY?

Since all three look different, the change in one value changes the other. Does it mean, only one entry for key is being made into `HashMap`  either `e1, e2 or null`? Because all are treated to be same key.

Comment: The values of e1 and e2 are null. Java is pass-by-value, and will pass only the value of a variable, when that variable is used as call parameter. That is the variable will never be reassigned inside the function, and the parameter name in the function will have nothing to do with any variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashMap having null as key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697609/hashmap-having-null-as-key)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

***`HashMap`*** does not call  hashcode when *null* is passed as key and null Key is handled as special case.

### **Put Method**

***`HashMap`*** puts *null* key in bucket *0* and maps *null* as key to passed value. HashMap does it by linked list data structure. HashMap uses linked list data structure internally.

Linked list data structure used by ***`HashMap`*** (a static class in `HashMap.java`)

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;
        final int hash;
}
```

In Entry class the *K* is set to *null* and value mapped to value passed in put method.

### **Get Method**

While in ***`Hashmap`*** get method the checks if key is passed as *null*. Search Value for *null* key in bucket *0*.

**Hence there can only be one null key in one** `hashmap` **object.**

Comment: Just fyi, The answer is perfectly correct, but there are slight changes about HashMap implementation since java 1.8. Instead of linked list a balanced trees  can be used as "buckets"

Answer (score 9):

If you pass `null` as map key, it will go to `0 bucket`. All values of null key will go there. That is why it returns same value, cause all keys you are providing are `null` and are in the same bucket of your HashMap.

Comment: what if i inserted two values with NULL as key, v1 and v2. while fetching which one i will get???? Always last one ?

Comment: @dineshkandpal yes, always the last one (v2)

Answer (score 4):

Incase of **null** key , Hashmap implementation consider it as special case and doesnot call hashCode method instead it stores Entry object to 0 bucket location.

Answer (score 2):

A HashMap can only store one value per key. If you want to store more values, you have to use a MultivalueHashMap (Google Guava and Apache Commons Collections contain implementations of such a map).

e1 and e2 have the value null, since you don't assign any object to them. So if you use those variables, the key of that map entry is also null, which leads to your result. Null doesn't have any hashcode, but is tolerated as key in the HashMap (there are other Map implementations which don't allow Null as key).

Answer (score 1):

When you put NULL to HashMap there is special check if you are trying to put NULL as key (called **putForNullKey()**). It is special case and works not like you are trying to put some object which is not null, and as you may see it even doesn't go to hash calculation.

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}

private V putForNullKey(V value) {
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[0]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (e.key == null) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    modCount++;
    addEntry(0, null, value, 0);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your inserts into the HashMap:

```
map.put(e2, "25");
map.put(e1, "");
map.put(null, null);
map.put(null, "30");
```

pass `null` as the key because in your code **e1** and **e2** are set to `null`. Using the same key allows to store only one value. In this case value stored in the map for the `null` key is updated after each of the `put` calls in your code.