# Java Null Object that is used in Hash Tables and Comparables

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, equality, comparable

I have an object that represents an `UNKNOWN` value, or "Null object".

As in SQL, this object should never be equal to anything, including another `UNKNOWN`, so `(UNKNOWN == UNKNOWN) -> false`.

The object is used, however, in hashtables and the type is `Comparable`, so I created a class as follows:

```
public class Tag implements Comparable {    
  final static UNKNOWN = new Tag("UNKNOWN");
  String id;

  public Tag(String id) { 
    this.id = id; 
  }

  public int hashCode(){
    return id.hashCode();
  }

  public String toString(){
    return id;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o){    
    if (this == UNKNOWN || o == UNKNOWN || o == null || !(o instanceof Tag))
      return false;

    return this.id.equals(((Tag)o).id);
  }

  public int compareTo(Tag o){
    if (this == UNKNOWN)
      return -1;
    if (o == UNKNOWN || o == null)
      return 1;

    return this.id.compareTo(o.id);
  }
}
```

But now `compareTo()` seems "inconsistent"?

Is there a better way to implement `compareTo()`?

Comment: If two objects can be identical in value and yet still not be equal, then they cannot be `Comparable`, as it would break the contract.

Comment: It's not just inconsistent, it's wrong. If `a.compareTo(b) < 0`, it's required that `b.compareTo(a) > 0`.

Comment: That's my worry exactly, so how do I implement a `compareTo()` with an UNKNOWN object that can not be equal other UNKNOWN objects?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What would SQL do?

Comment: logically you can not make something not equal to itself, that just does not make any sense

Comment: Have you ever heard of the SQL Specification? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It's actually quite common. JavaScript has it also with `NaN`, where all attempts to sort an array containing `NaN` have undefined outputs, and all comparisons with `NaN` always return `false`.

Comment: but you can not use `NaN` as a key in a HashTable because you could never retrieve the value associated with it because you could never match it, you kind of prove my point there in your comment

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm just saying that "not logical" doesn't mean "not allowed." It means that you have to create a well defined specification of what operations will have undefined output.

Comment: Duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932730/hashmap-with-null-key-and-null-value and 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981852/why-hashtable-does-not-allows-null-keys-or-values

Comment: I don't see the big deal. Choose an order (null = 0, nulls first, nulls last etc.) and implement it. It won't be consistent with equals, but that's not a strict requirement. As long you're aware of the caveats (e.g. it'll work as key for `TreeMap`, but not `HashMap`), it's your decision.

Comment: Close-voter: this is not an opinion-based question. It's a serious design question. See my answer for information on how SQL and Java deal with such things. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43796827/1441122

Comment: The `Tag` class needs to implement `Comparable<Tag>`. You should also probably make `id` be `final`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) mentions this situation:

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that
>
> ```
> (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))
> ```
>
> Generally speaking, any class that implements the `Comparable` interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

Therefore, if you want your object to be `Comparable` and yet still not allow two `UNKNOWN` objects to be equal via the `equals` method, you must make your `compareTo` "Inconsistent with equals."

An appropriate implementation would be:

```
public int compareTo(Tag t) {
    return this.id.compareTo(t.id);
}
```

Otherwise, you could make it explicit that `UNKNOWN` values in particular are not `Comparable`:

```
public static boolean isUnknown(Tag t) {
    return t == UNKNOWN || (t != null && "UNKNOWN".equals(t.id));
}

public int compareTo(Tag t) {
    if (isUnknown(this) || isUnknown(t)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("UNKNOWN is not Comparable");
    }
    return this.id.compareTo(t.id);
}
```

Comment: I think that you're on to something here.  I don't want the IllegalStateException -- if I had wanted to risk a Runtime Exception then I would keep the undefined value as a regular Java `null` and get a NullPointerException.  But the quote that you cited from the compareTo() documentation might be what I was looking for.  I'm upvoting your answer for now, and will accept it if deemed the best solution.

Comment: I agree that this is *one* way to go: but you have to understand that you are about to open a can of worms. I would rather step back quite a bit; and rethink your whole approach. Will update my answer on that part in a second.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct that your `compareTo()` method is now inconsistent. It violates several of the requirements for this method. The `compareTo()` method must provide a *total order* over the values in the domain. In particular, as mentioned in the comments, `a.compareTo(b) < 0` must imply that `b.compareTo(a) > 0`. Also, `a.compareTo(a) == 0` must be true for every value.

If your `compareTo()` method doesn't fulfil these requirements, then various pieces of the API will break. For example, if you sort a list containing an `UNKNOWN` value, then you might get the dreaded "Comparison method violates its general contract!" exception.

How does this square with the SQL requirement that `null` values aren't equal to each other?

For SQL, the answer is that it bends its own rules somewhat. There is a section in the Wikipedia article you cited that covers the behavior of things like [grouping and sorting in the presence of `null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#When_two_nulls_are_equal:_grouping.2C_sorting.2C_and_some_set_operations). While `null` values aren't considered equal to each other, they are also considered "not distinct" from each other, which allows `GROUP BY` to group them together. (I detect some specification weasel wording here.) For sorting, SQL requires `ORDER BY` clauses to have additional `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAST` in order for sorting with nulls to proceed.

So how does Java deal with IEEE 754 `NaN` which has similar properties? The result of any comparison operator applied to `NaN` is false. In particular, `NaN == NaN` is false. This would seem to make it impossible to sort floating point values, or to use them as keys in maps. It turns out that Java has its own set of special cases. If you look at the specifications for [`Double.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-) and [`Double.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), they have special cases that cover exactly these situations. Specifically,

```
Double.NaN == Double.NaN // false

Double.valueOf(Double.NaN).equals(Double.NaN) // true!
```

Also, `Double.compareTo()` is specified so that it considers `NaN` equal to itself (it is *consistent with equals*) and `NaN` is considered larger than every other `double` value including `POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

There is also a utility method [`Double.compare(double, double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-) that compares two primitive `double` values using these same semantics.

These special cases let Java sorting, maps, and so forth work perfectly well with `Double` values, even though this violates IEEE 754. (But note that primitive `double` values do conform to IEEE 754.)

How should this apply to your `Tag` class and its `UNKNOWN` value? I don't think you need to follow SQL's rules for `null` here. If you're using `Tag` instances in Java data structures and with Java class libraries, you'd better make it conform to the requirements of the `compareTo()` and `equals()` methods. I'd suggest making `UNKNOWN` equal to itself, to have `compareTo()` be consistent with equals, and to define some canonical sort order for `UNKNOWN` values. Usually this means sorting it higher than or lower than every other value. Doing this isn't terribly difficult, but it can be subtle. You need to pay attention to all the rules of `compareTo()`.

The `equals()` method might look something like this. Fairly conventional:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }

    return obj instanceof Tag && id.equals(((Tag)obj).id);
}
```

Once you have this, then you'd write `compareTo()` in a way that relies on `equals()`. (That's how you get the consistency.) Then, special-case the unknown values on the left or right-hand sides, and finally delegate to comparison of the `id` field:

```
public int compareTo(Tag o) {
    if (this.equals(o)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (this.equals(UNKNOWN)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (o.equals(UNKNOWN)) {
        return 1;
    }

    return id.compareTo(o.id);
}
```

I'd recommend implementing `equals()`, so that you can do things like filter `UNKNOWN` values of a stream, store it in collections, and so forth. Once you've done that, there's no reason not to make `compareTo` consistent with `equals`. I wouldn't throw any exceptions here, since that will just make standard libraries hard to use.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: you shouldn't.

You have contradiction requirements here. Either your tag objects have an implicit order (that is what Comparable expresses) OR you can have such "special" values that are not equal to anything, not even themselves.

As the other excellent answer and the comments point out: yes, you *can* somehow get there; for example by simply allowing for a.compare(b) < 0 and b.compare(a) < 0 at the same time; or by throwing an exception.

But I would simply be **really** careful about this. You are breaking a **well established** contract. And the fact that some javadoc says: "breaking the contract is OK" is not the point - breaking that contract means that all the people working on this project have to understand this detail.

Coming from there: you could go forward and simply throw an exception within `compareTo()` if a or b are UNKNOWN; by doing so you make at least clear that one shouldn't try to `sort()` a `List<Tag>` for example. But hey, wait - how would you find out that UNKNOWN is present in your list? Because, you know, UNKNOWN.equals(UNKNOWN) returns false; and `contains()` is using equals.

In essence: while technically possible, this approach causes **breakages** wherever you go. Meaning: the fact that SQL supports this concept doesn't mean that you should **force** something similar into your java code. As said: this idea is very much "off standards"; and is prone to *surprise* anybody looking at it. Aka "unexpected behavior" aka *bugs*.

Comment: The documentation gets away with this issue by stating that `compareTo(null)` throws a `NullPointerException`. I would find it reasonable that an `UNKNOWN` value would be a similar case where it's necessary to throw an exception.

Comment: SQL has it both ways. It's a little unintuitive, but it works.

Comment: Both comments make sense; I tried to factor them into my answer. Thank you @4castle and Mr. shmosel!

Comment: I was not suggesting that it would acceptable to allow *for a.compare(b) < 0 and b.compare(a) < 0 at the same time*. In fact, I already [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795877/java-null-object-that-is-used-in-hash-tables-and-comparables/43796013#comment74632339_43795877) to the contrary. I meant that having a value not equal to itself does not, logically or contractually, preclude implicit ordering.

Answer (score 0):

#### A couple seconds of critical thinking:

There is already a `null` in Java and you can not use it as a key for a reason.

> If you try and use a key that is not equal to anything else including
> itself you can **NEVER** retrieve the value associated with that key!

Comment: I don't want ever to retrieve the value associated with "that key".  The value is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: then why do you want to put it in a `Hashtable` to begin with then, it makes no sense and not a very well thought out solution. This is an X/Y Problem at best.

Comment: Because all other values, i.e. all the values that are KNOWN, should be retrieved fast.  The UNKNOWN value is an edge case.

Comment: you miss my entire point, if the value associated with it is `null` or `undefined` and will never be access why even put in the container? There is a reason that `null` is not allowed to be a key, that reason applies to your X/Y Problem.