# Why null is not allowed in ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java

Why a `null` key is not allowed in `ConcurrentHashMap`?

In `HashMap`, it is allowed and in `HashTable` it is not allowed.

Already visited the link :[Why does ConcurrentHashMap prevent null keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698638/why-does-concurrenthashmap-prevent-null-keys-and-values)

But I need the actual reason not the guesses.

Comment: maybe this brings a light to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932730/hashmap-with-null-key-and-null-value

Comment: The link is related to HashMap and I want to know why null is not allowed in ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @nafas, I have already visited the same link and I am not getting the proper explanation. That post mainly contains different guesses of different people.I want to know the exact reason behind that.

Comment: the provided dup link by Jon Skeet is spot on answer.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you should allow that? Imo they could have banned `null` from the maps completely. If it's not written in the documentation and you don't ask the author, a user guess is as close as you can get. Also, note that it could be a pure design choice, without any particular good reason. Maybe it has to do with the internal implementation of the map, maybe it is hard to manage a `null` as key. Maybe it is hard to manage it for possible future updates to the implementation.

Comment: @Zabuza You want to say that no one knows the exact reason and we can only guess that.